# Understanding specific type of inheritance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

Could somebody please explain what does this kind of inheritance in TypeScript mean? There is any chance to create alias for everything what we have after extends keyword?

```
class MyClass extends (FooClass as { new(): BarClass })
```

Comment: It's combining regular [class inheritance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#inheritance) with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  You are telling the compiler that `MyClass` is a subtype of `BarClass` but the `BarClass` constructor (if there is one) will not be part of the prototype chain... instead it will use the `FooClass` constructor as its superclass at runtime.  Not sure why you'd want to do this without more concrete example (as in a [mcve]).

Comment: Can you show the real code where you encountered this? There are few examples of why you might need to do this, IMO all of them a bad sign of code health. Ideally you would never have to assert a class to another constructor.

Comment: https://github.com/bterlson/strict-event-emitter-types/blob/master/README.md. I like this project and I would like to use it.. I didn't find any other better typed events emitters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that classes in TypeScript exist both in 'value' space (the realm of objects that exist at run time) and in 'type' space (the realm of concepts that only exist at compile time). Consider how this gets compiled into ES5:

```
class MyClass extends (FooClass as { new(): BarClass }) { }
```

Becomes:

```
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyClass, _super);
    function MyClass() {
        return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    return MyClass;
}(FooClass));
```

Note that `FooClass` is passed in as part of the type definition idiom as a reference to the `_super` class, but `BarClass` isn't referenced at all (hint: because it's in 'type' space). So the `FooClass` here references the *value* of `FooClass`, but assumes the value of `FooClass` is of type `{ new(): BarClass }`.

In other words the type that's used here for the purpose of type checking is just `{ new(): BarClass }` but at run-time, `MyClass` will actually extend `FooClass`. I suppose how much difference this distinction really makes depends on the exact definitions of `FooClass` and `BarClass`.